# Stop Excel from showing a graph value which is different from the data?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

My problem is that excel graphs are showing my data differently from the data that I'm using to plot it.

From the example below, the purple line `Ebay/Play etc.` is being plotted, but from point 28, the value is `1` but it is plotted around `180`.

[image]

How do I stop Excel from showing a graph value which is different from the data?

Comment: obviously some of the data is "out of range"

Comment: It looks like you have a Stacked Line Chart. If so, can you convert it to a standard Line Chart and post that result-the differences that type may plot correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry folks seem to be having problem logging across from stackoverflow.
Many Thanks to Rene & Dav, for taking the time to look at my question.

Dav, your suggestion worked beautifully and was the cause of my problem. I've fixed it in the attached.
Rene, I of course checked to see the data was not out of range and you'll see from the original image that excel was showing the value as '1' but showing on the graph as 1500 ish

[image]

Comment: What is Dav's suggestion? Please update the answer to include it

Comment: Dav suggested that the problem with the graph was that it was a 'stacked' line graph and not a regular line graph.  I was able to correct it by RMB 'Change Chart type' then selecting the regular 'line' graph option